# How to use a subquery in a join clause in Laravel's query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'd like to build following query in Eloquent:

```sql
SELECT products.*
FROM products
LEFT JOIN product_translations ON product_translations.id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM product_translations
    WHERE product_id = products.id
      AND title IS NOT NULL
      AND language IN (?, ?)
    ORDER BY FIELD(language, ?, ?)
    LIMIT 1
)
WHERE is_published = ?
ORDER BY product_translations.title ASC;
```

This is my attempt:

```php
$languages = ['de', 'en'];
$placeholders = collect($languages)->map(fn() => '?')->join(', ');

$subquery = ProductTranslation::query()
    ->select('id')
    ->whereRaw('product_id = products.id')
    ->whereNotNull('title')
    ->whereIn('language', $languages)
    ->orderByRaw("FIELD(language, $placeholders)", $languages)
    ->limit(1);

$query = Product::query()
    ->addSelect('products.*')
    ->leftJoin('product_translations', 'product_translations.id', '=', DB::raw("({$subquery->toSql()})"))
    ->mergeBindings($subquery->toBase())
    ->where('is_published', false)
    ->orderBy('product_translations.title');

$query->get();
```

But in that way the bindings order will be incorrect. I expected this: `'de'`, `'en'`, `'de'`, `'en'`, `1`. But the actual produced query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT products.*
FROM products
LEFT JOIN product_translations ON product_translations.id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM product_translations
    WHERE product_id = products.id
      AND title IS NOT NULL
      AND language IN ('de', 'en')
    ORDER BY FIELD(language, 1, 'de')
    LIMIT 1
)
WHERE is_published = 'en'
ORDER BY product_translations.title ASC;
```

How do I accomplish that? I've seen no way to use a subquery in a join clause.

**Update:**
Here is the migration with test records:

```php
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->boolean('is_published');
});
Schema::create('product_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
    $table->string('language', 2);
    $table->string('title');
});

DB::table('products')->insert(['is_published' => 1]);
DB::table('product_translations')->insert([
    ['product_id' => 1, 'language' => 'en', 'title' => 'Test EN'],
    ['product_id' => 1, 'language' => 'de', 'title' => 'Test DE'],
    ['product_id' => 1, 'language' => 'es', 'title' => 'Test ES'],
]);
```

Comment: Try using `leftJoinSub`. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins Check under subquery joins under Advanced Joins

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't look right. You may just use a subquery instead of a table for joining. But I'd like to join against a table and use the subquery in the "ON" clause.

Comment: I wonder If you could share migration and a data dump or an sql dump. I would like to give it a go..

Comment: Sure, I've added both. Thanks!

Comment: Oh i wish I had noticed this earlier, but instead of merge bindings you would actually need to use `addBindings`. Ill post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `mergeBindings` you would need `addBinding`:

```
$query = Product::query()
    ->addSelect('products.*')
    ->leftJoin('product_translations', 'product_translations.id', '=', DB::raw("({$subquery->toSql()})"))
    ->addBinding($subquery->getBindings(), 'join') //use add bindings.
    ->where('is_published', false)
    ->orderBy('product_translations.title');
```

`mergeBingings` constructs the bindings on the entire query by type. As in, order, where, having... and so on. `addBinding` is needed to merge bindings on individual join levels.

---

I've tested this with the data you provided and here is the binding array when `addBinding` is used.

```
"bindings" => array:5 [▼
      0 => "de"
      1 => "en"
      2 => "de"
      3 => "en"
      4 => false
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It would be great if a subquery in the on clause was implemented as native function in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, this code worked for me:

```
->join(
    DB::raw($subqueryString), 
    function ($join) { 
        $join->on('table1.id', '=', 'table2.id'); 
    }
)
```

Example:

```
$results = Translation::selectRaw('t1.*')
            ->from('translations AS t1')
            ->join(DB::raw("
                (SELECT MAX(id) AS id, release_id
                FROM translations
                WHERE release_id = 3
                "), function ($join) {
                $join->on('t1.id', '=', 't2.id');
            })
            ->orderBy('t1.release_id', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```